# How to iport 4 images in new form

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am new in JavaFX, this is my code. This application has a button, If you click on the button opens new form. Does anyone know how to insert 4  picture into a new form?

```
package javafxwindow;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
```

Packages that I used. The class JavaFXWindow.

```
public class JavaFXWindow extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
Button btn = new Button();
btn.setText("Open a New Window");
btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
    Label secondLabel = new Label("Hello");

    StackPane secondaryLayout = new StackPane();
    secondaryLayout.getChildren().add(secondLabel);

    Scene secondScene = new Scene(secondaryLayout, 200, 100);

    Stage secondStage = new Stage();
    secondStage.setTitle("New Stage");
    secondStage.setScene(secondScene);

    secondStage.show();

});

StackPane root = new StackPane();
root.getChildren().add(btn);

Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

primaryStage.setTitle("java-buddy.blogspot.com");
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();

primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> Platform.exit());

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Comment: Create VBox root2 = new VBox(); then create four ImageViews. Add each image to an ImageView add the imageViews to root2 add root two to new Scene add new scene to secondStage.

Comment: Very similar to what you did to create the primaryStage.

Comment: I am not a fan of this type of programming. I suggest you learn about Model-View-Control. This will allow you to use apps like SceneBuilder to build your view. Then you only have to concentrate on you logic.

Comment: `StackPane secondaryLayout = new StackPane(imageView1, imageView2, imageView3, imageView4);` This does what you're attempting to do according to the question description, however the images will be placed on top of each other... But since you did not specify any else about the way the images should be added, this seems to solve your problem, right???